# gapi auth client use unsafe eval if response type is id_token

Tags: oauth, google-api-client

When google javascript client library is used in chrome extension, 'unsafe-eval' permission is required when response type is id_token. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: I can't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve; using eval() function in a Chrome Extension requires 'unsafe-eval' permission to be declared in the manifest.json, regardless the presence of the Goole Javascript Client Library inside that extension. Maybe you can go deeper explaining your case, and there can be a solution to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

last time I checked the JSAPI client library wasn't supported in Chrome Extensions. Even if it is, I would strongly suggest you avoid using it.

It's easier and safer to use the built-in chrome.identity API to handle the oauth and then roll your own Google API calls.

Answer (score 1):

Using eval() function in a Chrome Extension requires 'unsafe-eval' permission to be declared in the manifest.json, regardless the presence of the Goole Javascript Client Library inside that extension.

> **Evaluated JavaScript**. The policy against eval() and its relatives like setTimeout(String), setInterval(String), and new Function(String)
>   can be relaxed by adding 'unsafe-eval' to your policy:
>
> "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
>
> However, we strongly recommend against doing this. These functions are
>   notorious XSS attack vectors.

See the official Google Documentation for more information about
[Content Security Policy](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

Comment: I am not using eval,  but gapi does.